# Setting up MBR drive with Dos/ Windows 10/ Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, server, partitioning, mbr

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on an HDD partitioned as MBR with Dos and Windows 10 installed as well. I worked with a gentleman yesterday that was a great help but I stumped him as well as myself. I have the HDD pre-formatted as such:

1. 9.77GB Fat32 first for the Dos partition with boot files installed
2. 823.00GB NTFS second for Windows 10
3. 512MB formatted as cleared
4. 117GB formatted as cleared
   I know that MBR works as I was able to do an Ubuntu only install with 2 cleared partitions only. 1 partition I set up as ext4 and mounted at /
   the other partition automatically set itself as 512MB Fat32 and mounted at /boot/efi.
   I tried installing Windows and Dos behind these but the update-grub command fails to see the new OS even though I am able to at least select the window installation through the Bios. I do remember seem to remember that Dos is pretty selfish and always wants to be the very first partition.

I should mention that I have been successfully running the above configuration using Ubuntu Server 16.04 for a number of years. However updating in not a viable option do to Firewall restrictions.

And before anyone asks, I do have a GPT drive successfully set up with Windows / Ubuntu Server 20.04 using a pre-formatted drive. Do to the nature of my work, we are in need of Dos and the MBR setup.

**Main storage selection:**
[image: Main storage selection]

**as /boot**
[image: as /boot]

**as /boot/efi**
[image: As /boot/efi]

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide. I will be out of office for the next few days so may not be able to respond until Monday at the earliest.
James

Comment: So you are going to install using Legacy BIOS boot mode? Also can you please say where you face a problem and what you have already tried?

Comment: Yes installation needs to occur using Legacy Bios mode. With a pre-formatted HDD as above, or pre-formatted with the last two as FAT32 on the 512MB, and ext4 on the 117GB the installation will not let me proceed when I reach choosing the storage at step 5 here. https://www.linuxtechi.com/ubuntu-20-04-lts-server-installation-guide/. It asks for a boot disk even after selecting the 512 I have set up for this. I can successfully install onto MBR drive so long as Ubuntu is the only partitions set up, or I start with a completely clear HDD. Sorry for the late response as I was on vacation. James

Comment: Can you post a screenshot. I hope you know that MBR can't handle more than 4 partitions... So you will have to make your Ubuntu partitions into logical partitions except the 512

Comment: I have it set to 4 Partition only right now. As I recall Dos does not like to be anything but first on the list. and that is why I have it set as such.

Comment: What happens if you don't make a /boot partition and select the whole drive. I don't think a /boot partitions is necessary. BTW, why did you try to make a /boot/efi? Isn't /boot/efi for UEFI? Reading @Nmath's comment, do you have windows as UEFI? Doesn't look like that for me

Comment: Is your disk partitioned as GPT or MBR? I ask this because of "I do have a GPT drive successfully set up with Windows / Ubuntu Server 20.04 using a pre-formatted drive."

Comment: It is. And no Windows is also MBR. I am just grasping at straws at this point. If using the entire HDD it automatically formats as UEFI. If I pre-format as MBR and 2 partitions as clear it will install as MBR without issue. It is just doing it with DOS and Windows or just windows for that matter that has an issue. As Nmath points out I could just switch HDD's, but that is not an attractive option as many different people will be using the platforms, and space a weight are at a premium. Also to answer Nmath, DOS is at least for the time being, required as it is being used to test hardware.

Comment: Sasuke I do have a requirment to have a Drive set up as GPT as well. That went very easy. It is just the MBR that is causing me grief. I have even tried setting up a hybrid HDD with no luck.

Comment: Sorry no I cannot without a signed Non disclosure agreement on file, other than it is for hardware testing requirements. Other than that I know that MBR is different than GPT and they are mutually exclusive. (With the exception of a hybrid drive that is flakey at best.) As I said earlier do to space, weight, and personnel, if it weren't for the DOS requirement, I would not be pursuing this avenue. Again thanks for any help.

Comment: Just wanted to bump the thread. Also wanting to reiterate the fact I do have a working GPT drive with Windows 10 and Ubuntu Server 20.04. No issues what so ever there, And yes I have a need for that. I am still looking for a single drive, MBR solution for DOS, Windows 10, and Ubuntu Server 20.04. And yes I know what I am asking for is a dinosaur. And Yes I do have a need for DOS as antiquated as it might be. I would love to not be pursuing  this, but it is what was handed to me to implement as I did with DOS, Windows 10, and Ubuntu Server 16.04. Again thank you for any and all help.

Comment: @JamesVanGorder You should edit your question and add that last comment. Also, make sure you reply with @ so others won't miss your comments. I missed yours for a few days and came across it by accident. BTW, **Did you make sure you are installing the Legacy version of Ubuntu and not the UEFI one?**

Comment: By that I mean when booting into your USB, did you chose the option that says UEFI in front?

Comment: Sasuke Uchiha, Yes I did ensure installing with the legacy version of Ubuntu. However I found a work around to the problem of running the update process that I encountered early on. I'm hopeful that the MBR procedure will now be short lived. Thanks to all that helped and replied to my questions. This is a fantastic community.